# Terminating active application processes from/within application switcher  in gnome-shell 3.2

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

in gnome shell when several applications are open in different workspaces i use applications switcher <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in a PC) to active/switch to the app/workspace i want to use.

is it possible to terminate an application within the application switcher, like in the mac environment with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in a PC) instead of using the window control icons or add this function somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default shortcut for that. The [Power Alt-Tab extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/58/power-alt-tab/) should fit your needs, though.

According to the author, the extension:

> Replace alt tab behavior, iterate over available workspaces and
>   windows, **close windows directly from the pager**. NOW KEYBINDINGS ARE
>   SWAPPED (alt-tab iterates over windows, alt-keyAboveTab iterates over
>   workspaces).

Comment: thank you very much Alexandre, for your fast reply and suggestion. that basically is what i was looking for. two detailes render this extension uselesss for me though which is to bad!! the extension switches from icons preview to window preview and it only works for open windows and applications in the activated workspace.

Comment: @v2r I checked the [project issues page](https://github.com/emerinohdz/PowerAltTab/issues/) and it seems like people want the same features you do. Maybe you could ask for those features there by adding/commenting in a issue.

Comment: i probably should have done so already! you are absolutely right Alexandre. i´ll do that and thank you for the pointer!!